# adding post to database by php form and category

Tags: php, html

I want to post the value selected from the category table to software table by a php form but when I post the form it is only posting the id instead of the value I selected.

```
<form name="post" id="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <select name="category" id="category">
     <option value="<?php echo $category">
     <?php
       $categoryqu="SELECT * FROM categories";
       $results=mysql_query($categoryqu);
       while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){
         $id=$row['cid'];
         $name=$row['name'];
         echo"<option value='".$id."'>".$name."</option>";
       }
     ?> 
    </option>
  </select>

  <input placeholder="Title" name="title" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" type="text">
  <input placeholder="Title" name="title" value="<?php echo $link; ?>" type="text">
  <input placeholder="Title" name="title" value="<?php echo $description; ?>" type="text">
</form>
```

Category table is 
[Category Table Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSCdq.png)
 and it is posting only id instead of category names.

[Here is the table posting the data from dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gKTN.png)
when I post the form it is posting all is well but only the value of selected category is posting the value "id" but I want it post the selected value to the database where and what is the error in this code.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, [edit #18600217](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18600217) should be approved (I mixed up my tabs during review).

Answer (score 0):

The error you describe with "*but when i post the form it posting the id only instead of the value i selected*" is the wanted behavior of submitting a [HTML select](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp).

First of all you should make sure, that you really need the `$name` value when saving the data into your database. You should be able to make the same relations with the `$id` as well.

If you really need it, you can either use the `$name` as the value attribute instead. If you do this the `$id` will not be saved.

```
echo"<option value='" . $name . "'>" . $name . "</option>";
```

Or you could create a concatenation of both, that you later explode.

```
echo"<option value='" . $id . '|' . $name. "'>" . $name . "</option>";
```

Then later when analysing the POST result:

```
list($id, $name) = explode('|', $selectedValue, 2);
```

Comment: echo"<option value='" . $name . "'>" . $name . "</option>"; its showing value "0"

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```html
<form name="post" id="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<select name="category" id="category">
<?php
$categoryqu="SELECT * FROM categories";
$results=mysql_query($categoryqu);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){
$id=$row['cid'];
$name=$row['name'];?>
<option value="<?php echo $id;?>"><?php echo $name; ?></option>
}?> 
</select>

<input placeholder="Title" name="title" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" type="text">
<input placeholder="Title" name="title" value="<?php echo $link; ?>" type="text">
<input placeholder="Title" name="title" value="<?php echo $description; ?>" type="text">
```